# Online Microsoft Docs Visual Basic.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am steadily getting to grips with VB.net using Visual Studio 2019 and find myself going back and forth to the Microsoft Docs for help and code examples.

I am finding that when I search the Microsoft Docs, it more often returns examples for C# and not VB.Net. Does Microsoft have a specific Docs page for VB.net, ive tried searching but cannot seem to locate one.

Thanks

Comment: You can choose the language. Just click the `</>` icon on the top right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some instances where only C# examples are available but generally speaking VB will be available too. Select the language just below the Search field at the top of the page:

[image]